# How can I create keys for an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I create keys for an array of values in javascript like this?

```
const array = ["NodeJs", "Javascript", "React"]
```

and transform it like this

```
const array = [{"name": "NodeJs"}, {"name": "Javascript"}, {"name": "React"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = ["NodeJs", "Javascript", "React"];
const newArr = arr.map(name => ({name})); // or arr.map(item => ({name: item}))

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using `Array.from(iterable, mappingFunction)` which will return a new array with objects `{name: name}`:

```js
const array = ["NodeJs", "Javascript", "React"];
const mapArray = Array.from(array, (name) => ({name}));
console.log(mapArray);
```